# Client-side HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE access? JavaScript? I don't see a JQuery wrapper. Static pages to detect preferred language!

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, internationalization

I'm trying to access user's language preference w/o using server code.

I'm looking for some JavaScript like this:

```
var language_array = jQuery.languagePreferences();
//en-ca,en;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.6,de-de;q=0.4,de;q=0.2
```

I know I can use HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE on server side, but what about in JavaScript/JQuery client-side static (non-server generated) page?

I've done a fair amount of Googling and have no clear browser agnostic solution.. how does JavaScript gain access to browsers' list of preferred user languages?  (as configured, say, in FireFox with Tools > Options > Content > Languages) It seems this is too hard.

If it's not possible it seems these might work:

1) [A question for ServerFault.com] Use server-side URL rewriting so Apache will respond with correct static page based on language preference?

2) Use AJAX on client to query server solely to read HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE?  Seems very convoluted!

Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you want the current language? Like `navigator.language`?  These don't *necessarily* match the headers, but I'm not sure the other is available.

Comment: Yes, the preferred language specified in the browser options dialog.  I'm not sure if that is the same as the current language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately it isn't possible to get at the equivalent of `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` using purely client side techniques. The closest you can get to it is the users current OS locale settings:

`navigator.userLanguage` for IE

and

`window.navigator.language` for most of the others (FF, Opera, etc).

I find that `navigator.language` and `navigator.browserLanguage` to be not very reliable (e.g. IE8 is incorrectly giving me *en-us* rather than *en-gb*).

Using ajax or modifying the routing as you've suggested will be only reliable way to go.