# Behavior and format of the date and time field within Portal

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-portals

[Behavior and format of the date and time field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/portals/behavior-format-date-time-field) states:

> User Local: The field values are displayed in the user’s local time
>   and formatted as per their current portal language/locale.

Where is the portal user's local time zone configured?

> By default, the portal uses the standard date/time formats specified by the website language settings.

Where are these settings?

Comment: maybe it uses the `accept-language header`? https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-lang-priorities which can be worked out client side with `javascript `, `jQuery` examlpe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079158/client-side-http-accept-language-access-javascript-i-dont-see-a-jquery-wrappe or server side with the http header.

Answer (score 1):

> Where is the portal user's local time zone configured?

Check out `adx_timezone` attribute on the contact record (contact is portal user)

> Where are these settings?

Look for `timezone/id` if you have in your [settings](https://community.adxstudio.com/products/adxstudio-portals/documentation/end-users-guide/content-management/settings-templates/site-settings/site-settings/). Based on your need [Set it](https://community.adxstudio.com/blogs/developer/adxstudio-portals-date-time-handling/).

This may be a missing piece in MS documentation. Since CRM portals built on top of AdX Studio portals, [this release notes](https://community.adxstudio.com/products/adxstudio-portals/releases/adxstudio-portals-7/release-notes/) can be helpful.

Under `7.0.0019 August 13, 2015`, it says:

> Date/Time format handling has been unified and improved.
>   Formats can now be specified as .NET custom DateTime format strings using [Site Settings](https://community.adxstudio.com/products/adxstudio-portals/documentation/end-users-guide/content-management/settings-templates/site-settings/), which will be applied to a page's body tag:
>
> - DateTime/DateFormat (default "M/d/yyyy")
> - DateTime/TimeFormat (default "h:mm tt")
> - DateTime/DateTimeFormat (no default)
>
> Breaking Change:  All data-format, data-dateformat, data-timeformat, and data-datetimeformat attributes currently in MomentJS format (if upgrading from 7.0.0008 or later) must be updated to instead use .NET custom DateTime format strings. Please note that .NET Standard DateTime format strings are not supported.

[Using Site Settings](https://community.adxstudio.com/products/adxstudio-portals/documentation/developers-guide/knowledge-base/using-site-settings/).

Comment: Thanks, but most of those settings you refer to are in the article I linked. I'm interested in the settings hinted at by the article, e.g. user and language specific settings.

Comment: Updated the answer like inline style.. pls check.